# How to check whether we can run plugin on iphone? Can we check using simulator?

Tags: macos, plugins, safari, webkit

How to check whether we can use plugin on iphone? Can we check using simulator and be assured it will run on the device? my plugin is working successfully on mac.

Now this code works on safari on mac but not on safari on simulator. Can someone tell me why?

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 5.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/1999  /REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">
   <html>
  <head>
   <title>Sample Speaking Plug-In</title>

  <script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

   function print() 
 {
    alert("running"+ document.getElementById('printid'));
//var plugin = document.embeds[0];
var plugin = document.getElementById('printid');
var data = plugin.myPrint();
alert(data);
(document.getElementById('t1')).value = data;
 }

  </script> 
</head>


   <body>

<!-- <embed  name="print" width="200px" height="400px" type="application/x-printText"     ></embed> -->
 <object type="application/x-printText" name="print1" id="printid" width="200px"   height="400px">
  </object>
<input type = "text" value = "horse" id="t1"/>
    <input type="button" value="print" onClick="print()"/>

  </body>

 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thrs no plugin for mobile safari. only for mac its available. Hope I find some alternative to plugin for mobile safari.